# Проблема в модуле telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ошибка в модуле telebot. Скачал pyTelegramBotAPI==0.3.0 и выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x1ag\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\telebot\bot.py", line 1, in module
  
import telebot

  File "C:\Users\x1ag\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 463
    
def async():
        
   ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Пытался переустанавливать модуль, но все та же ошибка. Также перезапускал PyCharm - не помогло.

Вот код программы:

```
import telebot

token = '123123hDhrj3289dse'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text.lower == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, юзер')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Telebot асинхронен, значит вам нужно использовать асинхронные функции.Просто напишите `async def get_text(message):`. А в вывод `await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, юзер')`. Вам бы почитать документацию к библиотеке. Спасибо.

Comment: async def get_text(message):
    if message.text.lower == 'привет':
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, юзер'). Спасибо за помощь. Изменил код. Все та же ошибка

Comment: Бред, телебот не асинхронный.

Comment: @X1AG https://pastebin.com/VfTmWPNC попробуйте вот это

Comment: @oleksandrigo Полностью вставил ваш код, конечно вставив токен, и выводит такую ошибку Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x1ag\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\telebot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telebot import TeleBot, types
  File "C:\Users\x1ag\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 463
    def async():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Наверное вы все такие неправильно установили телебот. Удалите проект. Сделайте чистый. Установите только pytelegramboapi. Вы возможно устанавливали telebot

Comment: @oleksandrigo Согласен, извиняюсь. Мельком просматривая исходники [ссылка](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/tree/master/telebot), ложно решил, что он асинхронный.

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да вы правы.  Переустановил и помогло. Странно) Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вы все такие неправильно установили телебот.
Удалите проект. Сделайте чистый. Установите только pytelegramboapi.
Вы, возможно, устанавливали telebot.

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
 
 
bot = TeleBot("token_here")
 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="text")
 
 
bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```